# How To Delete all items In ListView using ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android

I'm developing a Listview dynamically filled by a function that returns an ArrayAdapter which recieves a String parameter. This string parameter is the selected item of another dynamically filled Spinner.

When the function returns an ArrayAdapter with a number of items > 0, the Listview is sucessfully refreshed with the new items, but when the function returns 0 items on the ArrayAdapter, the listview doesn't clear the previous items. Here's the code I'm working on:

```
ManifiestoSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnManifiesto);
FacturasListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvwFacturas);

ManifiestoSpinner = (Spinner)
    ManifiestoSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            String EstadoID = EstadoSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            ArrayList<String> ListManifiestos = (ArrayList<String>)Factura.GetManifiestosByEstado(EstadoID);

            ActualizarManifiestSpinner(manifiesto);

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

private void ActualizarManifiestSpinner (ArrayList<String> manifiesto)
    {

    String[] datos = new String[manifiesto.size()];
    ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterManifiesto = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, manifiesto.toArray(datos));

    ManifiestoSpinner.setAdapter(AdapterManifiesto);

}

ManifiestoSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            String Manifiesto = ManifiestoSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String Estado = EstadoSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            fillData(Estado, Manifiesto);

            return;
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    });

private void fillData(String EstadoID, String ManifiestoID) {


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) FacturasListview.getAdapter();

    if(adapter!= null)
    {
        adapter.clear();
        FacturasListview.setAdapter(adapter);
        FacturasListview.invalidateViews();
    }

    List<String> from = Factura.GetListClientesByEstadoManifiesto(EstadoID, ManifiestoID);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.factura_row, R.id.text1 ,from);
    FacturasListview.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

When the List called from has from.size() = 0, the items previously show on the Listview are not cleared.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Nammari. I followed your recommendation but the FacturasListview doesn't have a method called notifyDatasetChanged(), the adapter does, so i got this code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) mFacturasListview.getAdapter();

if(adapter!= null)
{
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Still the Listview won't refresh the items. I'm looking for a method that will clear all the items of a ListView that recieves an ArrayAdapter. I'm uploading two pictures to show what I'm working on.

["Imagen 1"](http://www.mediafire.com/i/?nbc1b151fie6j3x)

In this case, the first spinner has a selecteditem().toString() = "POR RECIBIR", and based on that parameter, the second spinner is dynamically filled with the codes of all the documents having (document.State = "POR RECIBIR"). After the second spinner is filled, a third method called "fillData" fills the ListView with all the Customer's name included on the document. This is the code:

```
private void fillData(String EstadoID, String ManifiestoID) {


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) mFacturasListview.getAdapter();

if(adapter!= null)
{
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

List<String> from = Factura.GetListClientesByEstadoManifiesto(EstadoID, ManifiestoID);

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.factura_row, R.id.text1 ,from);
FacturasListview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

The problem occurs when the first spinner has a selecteditem().toString() = "POR ENTREGAR", and based on that parameter, we find 0 documents having (document.State = "POR ENTREGAR"). Here, the third method called "fillData" should clear all ListView items, but it doesn't. This is the image:

["Imagen 2"](http://www.mediafire.com/i/?frj1mdok2dhu3z3)

Answer (score 1):

In your `fillData` method

```
 if(adapter!= null)
    {
        adapter.clear();
        FacturasListview.setAdapter(adapter);// !!!!!!!
        FacturasListview.invalidateViews();
    }
```

after calling `adapter.clear();` setting the adapter of the `ListView` won't change anything 
just call FacturasListview.notifyDatasetChanged();

like this

```
 if(adapter!= null)
        {
            adapter.clear();
            FacturasListview.notifyDatasetChanged();
        }
```

this should clear all views in the list

in case you want to change the adapter of ListView i would make a custom array adapter with a method that takes the `List` and change the previous reference of the `List` in the `adapter` and after that call `notifyDatasetChanged();`
like this

```
class MyAdpater {
List<String> list; 
.....
.....


public void setAdpaterList(List<String>list){
this.list= list;
}
}
```

then after calling this method call `notifyDatasetChange()` on your adapter

Comment: Thanks Nammari. I followed your recommendation but there was a detail I posted.